# Ideas for an approach to display a list of constantly changing data

Tags: android, data-structures

My app connects to an IRC server and receives IRC messages. The messages are kept in a Service so they are preserved and updated when the GUI closes.

The problem I'm having is figuring out how to store the messages in-memory (with a maximum count limit) which allows me to fulfil all of the below

1. Update the data structure by either appending new messages or
   trimming away older ones
2. Use the data structure in a ListView
3. Not be required to make a copy of the data structure for the
   ListView

I can easily do 1 but the problem is mainly 2 & 3. Typically you have to pass a fixed-size data structure to a ListView and any changes usually require a complete refresh of the UI. I'd like to avoid refreshing in order to avoid performance problems.

Is this even possible and if so, what approach could I take?

Answer (score 0):

This might be side-stepping the problem, but perhaps you could pass yourself a serialized list of only message id's that have changed, and then only request them in the main thread. In this way, you can avoid performance issues from trying to update the entire list.

To answer your question, AFAIK you can only pass data via Intents and files for security reasons. If both sides are cooperating you might try ashmem